# Which site on the SE network can I ask about finding a good hosting/CDN for hosting my images?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

For example, the question I want to ask is like this:

> I am trying to make some funny apps for some celebrities and sometimes
>   it would reach a HUGE traffic while sometimes it won't. It's all by
>   luck, like if the celebrity retweet my link.
>
> I am looking for a good image hosting site to handle all the image
>   traffic. I am ok if it's not free. Is there any recommendations? I am
>   currently hosting the images on Cloudflare but it seems it's not
>   always cached. I don't know why.
>
> According to some existed data:
>
> 1. The request could be as high as 500,000 views per image per day.
> 2. We don't have a lot of different images. That means for the 500,000 views, there are only 1.png, 2.png to 20.png to be showed.
> 3. Averagely a user is only to view the picture once. That means for the 500,000 views, there are likely to be 500,000 users.
>
> I found a site called imgur but they seems not offering a high-traffic
>   solution API. I'd like to get some more recommendations that I can
>   try.

Is there a site on the SE network where I can ask this question?

Comment: If you were to post this on a site, you would probably get flagged for **primarily opinion-based**. I strongly recommend revising your question to receive a more factual answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would fit the bill, specifically tagged with [[web-hosting](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/tags/web-hosting/info)].

Do follow the advice in the tag wiki there, and read [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/20838) before asking your question.